# Format NSTimeInterval with NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I have a function in Swift that outputs the following information:

`1970-01-01 00:00:06 +0000`

`1970-01-01 00:00:07 +0000`

etc. It's essentially a stopwatch. I want to take that number and format it into just 00:00:00 with minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Here is the code I have:

```
func update() {
    currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    elapsedTime = currentTime - startDateInterval
    var testDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: elapsedTime)
    println(testDate)

}
```

`currentTime` is a reference to the date every time that `update()` is pinged (every .01 seconds)

`startDateInterval` is a reference to the date that is stored when the stopwatch is started.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is a

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
```

which you probably want to format like

```
    self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss:SSS"
    self.dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

and for the output you need to insert a date-difference in there, i.e.

```
    let now = NSDate()
    let timeintervalTotal = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(self.startDateTotal)
    self.labelTotalTime.text = self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeintervalTotal))
```